# What is the intended MassTransit middleware construct for setting mult-tenant scope values upon each message received?

Tags: rabbitmq, autofac, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with Autofac and need a way to interrogate inbound messages for a tenant Id which will be used to dynamically construct a connection string.  So the logical steps would be as follows:

1. A message is received
2. The tenant Id is retrieved from the message and a per-message-scoped component is used to set the tenant Id
3. A message consumer is resolved by the container which uses the per-message-scoped component to construct dependencies accordingly.

   MassTransit has an example of how to create message filters [here](https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/custom.html#message-type-filters).  At first glance this seems like a potential solution, but it doesn't appear that a new instance of a message filter is resolved using the same lifetime scope as is used to resolve the consumer for each message.

So my question is this:  Can message filters be used for this purpose?  If so, please provide an example or point to an example showing something similar (e.g. Anything where a DI-container is used which supports scopes for accessing per-message lifetime resources).  If not, what if any is the intended way of facilitating this need with MassTransit?

Comment: Not an answer, but there is tenant support for Autofac. It was contributed, so I don't really know how it works, but the unit test is [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Containers/MassTransit.Containers.Tests/Autofac_TenantContainerSpecs.cs).

Comment: Factoring in multi-tenancy into Autofac registrations is fairly easy by itself.  This is really more about understanding what middleware constructs are available in MassTransit and how they can be leveraged.

Comment: The consumer factory creates the lifetime scope for the consumer, as does the saga repository for sagas, etc. So anything above that in a middleware layer would not be part of that scope.

Comment: Though if you create a lifetime scope, and add it as a Payload to the consume context, the consumer/saga/etc. will use it. So you can create a lifetime scope at the higher level and the consumer will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on looking at the code, you should be able to create a new `ILifetimeScope` at the `ConsumeContext` level, and it will be used by the consumer. An example of the filter logic is included below.

```cs
public class LifetimeScopeFilter :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext>
{
    LifetimeScopeFilter(ILifetimeScope mainScope)
    {
        _mainScope = mainScope;
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        var scope = context.CreateFilterScope("lifetimeScope");
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext context, IPipe<ConsumeContext> next)
    {
        ILifetimeScope scope = null;

        try
        {
            context.GetOrAddPayload<ILifetimeScope>(() => scope = _mainScope.BeginLifetimeScope())

            await next.Send(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            scope?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, with this key bit of knowledge about the payload I was able to get my multi-tenant filter implementation working, so thanks 1000!  I have a fairly complete setup example in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/derekgreer/5ba7205593ada09141d3bc9e68ad116c

The only real question I guess I have about it at this point is how I'm actually going about registering the observer.  I had to pass cfg as a parameter because it can't be resolved at this point which feels a little messy.  If you know of a cleaner way let me know and I'll update the gist.

Comment: There are examples in the documentation of how to setup [the configuration](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/custom.html#message-type-filters) - those should get you started. It's observing the endpoint configuration, and then adding the filters as expected.